# Doctrine and Annotation : table annotation is not an annotation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

In the Windows environment, everything is fine and something strange happens when I deploy on the AIX environment.

Here is an example of some entity classes :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* AgentImpl
*
* @ORM\Table(name="AH2AGENT")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class AgentImpl
{
  ....
}
```

I have this exception :

```
[Semantical Error] The class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table" is not annotated with @Annotation. 
Are you sure this class can be used as annotation? 
If so, then you need to add @Annotation to the _class_ doc comment of "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table". 
If it is indeed no annotation, then you need to add @IgnoreAnnotation("ORM\Table") to the _class_ doc comment of class Cramif\AccueilBundle\Entity\AgentImpl
```

What does that mean ? What should I do to make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: Was `Doctrine` installed on the destination server? (via `composer`)

Comment: no... I copied the vendor folder

Comment: could it be an opcode stripping out docblocks ?

Comment: I have the same problem, eaccelerator not installed. I'm running with php 5.5.18 with fastcgi and opcache on windows (wamp) but opcache is configured to save and load docblocks comments (it worked fine until i did a composer update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is found. Hope it will help someone.

The fact is that we are using eAccelarator : it strips the comments out, so the annotation cannot work anymore.

add .htaccess or inside the vhost :

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

and it works